# What is a technical way to describe this style of website?

Tags: website-design, css, style-identification

I want to look up tutotirals for a few things but dont even know what to search for. What is the correct way to describe the following?

- The bar that is collected by the top of the screen and follows you after you start scrolling down
- This style of full screen website where there are static/absolute positioned images that are shown and hidden as you scroll down to show different imaged for each section.

Like: https://codeanywhere.com/

Answer (score 2):

Common terms are:

- Sticky Header
- Parallax Scrolling

You'll find many examples of Parallax scrolling, be careful not to go to over-the-top with it. Many do.

Comment: Can you give an example of over the top and your favourite implentation.

Comment: Not really :) There are thousands of sites which jumped on the parallax bandwagon a year or two ago. I don't really keep track of them. I simply see one and realize, "they implemented that well" or "That's a lot of pointless parallax." Essentially, don't bury the content with parallax movement. Remember the *function* of a web site and don't go too heavy into *form*.